# Cómo recibir varias respuestas de un input en HTML y pasarlas a un array en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un  `<input type="text">` y quiero que el cliente escriba varias respuestas, y luego pasar cada una a un array.
Puedo pedirle que separe sus respuestas con comas y luego usar split() para saparar la cadena recibida y convertirla en  array, pero me parece poco intuitivo para el cliente y puede generar errores muy fácilmente.
Hay alguna forma de que el cliente pueda escribir varias respuestas y que sea intuitiva la forma de separarlas?
Dejo un pequeño ejemplo del código.
De antemano agradezco mucho sus respuestas

```
  <label for="fabs">Cuáles son tus pasatiempos favoritos</label>
  <input type="text" id="favs">
```

Comment: Seria mejor que uses textarea para el control en vez de un input y como separador el usuario pueda usar los saltos de linea. Lo que debes hacer es recorrer la cadena char en char appeneandola en otra variable tipo string str_2+=str_1[i]; hasta llegar al salto de línea, guardamos el valor de str_2 en un array array[u]=str_2;u++;, vaciamos la variable str_2="" y repetimos todo hasta el final de esa cadenal. Suerte con tu tarea : ).

Comment: @DanielBriceño Gracias por tu respuesta, pero no entendí bien lo que dices. Me parece mejor hacer un  `.split(\n)` para separar las respuestas del `textarea` y formar el array.

Comment: Si... Es mucho más fácil.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un ejemplo para que analices, los ejemplos siempre ayudan

```
<input id="myInput" value="Some text..">
<button onclick="showHobbies()">Show hobbies</button>

<script>
    var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    let hobbies = [];
    input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
        event.preventDefault();
        hobbies.push(document.getElementById('myInput').value);
        document.getElementById('myInput').value = "";
      }
    });

    function showHobbies() {
        alert(hobbies.toString());
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas veces los ejemplos son útiles, pero ayudan más cuando tienen una explicación sobre cómo funcionan. Por favor, considera editar tu respuesta para describir el funcionamiento de tu propuesta.

Comment: ¿Tienes problemas para entender estas escasas líneas @Triby?

Comment: @Tiberius No se mucho de JavaScript, ¿Me regalas una explicación de lo que hiciste?

Comment: @Tiberius, piensa que quien pregunta no tiene el mismo nivel de conocimientos que tú y por eso es conveniente agregar una explicación, de forma que no solo solucione su problema, sino también sepa cómo funciona.

Comment: Para el evento keypress la función que maneja este evento se interesa cuando el usuario presiona Enter, cuando esto sucede lo agrega al final del vector hobbies mediante el método push lo que escribió el usuario. Luego limpia el input con cadena vacía "". La función showHobbies mediante un alert muestra el vector completo, es decir todo lo escrito por el usuario.